# are there any downsides to increasing the number of most recent items in a feed

Tags: rss, feed

The default number of items to show in a rss feed is 10 (Settings-Reading)

Is there any reason why I shouldn't show all items.

When I use feeds from other sources (not wordpress) it seems like they show all the items.

Is there any performance hit on the server for showing a large number of items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the number of items safely. Feed creation is pretty fast. It is just a simple loop through the latest posts, no scripts are loaded, no pagination, widgets or other expensive operations.

For your subscribers, more items are better, because they can explore your content faster. Make sure to use a full text feed, excerpts are rarely useful.

Comment: do you think it's ok to leave the value blank

Comment: @nilanjan You cannot leave it blank, it has to be a number greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

I did run into a problem with feed size.  Feedburner does not accept feeds if the size is large.  You get a message "feed filesize is larger than 576K"

"Your feed filesize is larger than 576K. You need to reduce its size in order for FeedBurner to process it. Tips for controlling feed file size with Blogger can be found in Tech Tips on FeedBurner Forums, our support site."

I am not sure what happens if the feed is small and then grows large.

It seems like the only way to control this is to reduce number of entries in wordpress.